# Protobuf: UninitializedMessageException is thrown but isInitialized() returns true

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

I'm experimenting a bit with Protobuf in Android and I'm a bit stuck. I'm trying to create a message but I get a `com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException: Message missing required fields`. However, `isInitialized()` returns true and I'm only using optional & repeated fields.

I'm sure I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Here is my proto file:

```
package mobile_app;

message Msg {
  enum Command {
    LOGIN = 0;
    LOGOUT = 1;
  }

  message Param {
    optional int32 param_id = 1;
    repeated string items = 2;
  }
  enum ErrorCode {
    LOGIN_OK = 0;
    LOGIN_FAILED = 1;
    UNKNOWN_PARAM_ID = 2;
  }
  optional Command command = 1;
  optional int32 param_id = 2;
  optional ErrorCode error_code = 3;
  optional string username = 4;
  optional string password = 5;
  repeated Param params = 6;
}
```

And my code:

```
// ...
Messages.Msg.Builder loginMessage = Messages.Msg.newBuilder();
loginMessage.setCommand(Messages.Msg.Command.LOGIN)
    .setUsername(username)
    .setPassword(password);

boolean isOk = loginMessage.isInitialized();  // returns true
Messages.Msg m = loginMessage.build();  // throws exception
// ...
```

I tried the code on a pure java application and it works just fine. So it seems it's an android specific problem.

Comment: Did you find something? Having exactly the same prob

Comment: Nope. Ended up using XML

Comment: Maybe too late, but after my comment I found something, which made perfectly sense to me. I filed a bug report for protobuf and got a comment already. Kudos for the find go to Patrick Linehan. See https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2217